# Firebase database and Android - How to destroy 'session' on logout?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

My android app has a sign out navigation item, when clicked, it will redirect the user to the Login activity.

How do I make sure the 'session' gets destroyed? I am asking this because I have this piece of code in Login activity which checks if the user is logged on (didn't sign out, but rather closed the application). If it's logged on, it redirects to MainActivity instead of LoginActivity:

```
private void setupFirebaseListener() {
mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
 @Override
 public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
  FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
  if (user != null) {
   startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
  } else {
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
   startActivity(intent);
   }
  }
 };
};

@Override
public void onStart() {
 super.onStart();
 FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}
@Override
public void onStop() {
 if (mAuthListener != null) {
  FirebaseAuth.getInstance().removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
 }
 super.onStop();
}
```

I will always get redirected to MainActivity (as of now), because the 'session' doesn't get destroyed in logout (of course, I didn't implement it because I don't know how, hence the question).

Comment: I don't see anything called "session" in your code.  Where are you getting the notion of a session?

Comment: @DougStevenson That's why I put it in quotation marks, just so people can get my point straight away. And also, I have a more of a web dev. background. Things are different in Android and Firebase database, and this is what I found out so far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the user to be logged out, you'll need to call `signOut`:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

Also see the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth#next_steps).

Comment: Awesome. For some reasons I was checking more complicated stuff but it was this easy, huh. Thanks!